# How to replace a numerical Scatter Plot axis with Text values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

Please see below for my current graph and table:

[image]

[image]

1. I would like to replace the the X-Axis (0, 1, 2, 3...) with the corresponding letter grades in the table (B, B+, A-...) with no duplicates and still maintain the order of the table.
2. I'd like to add the name of the animal to each dot, so for example the dot at (5, 11000000) would have "Dog" next to it.

Can anyone provide detailed instructions on how to accomplish this? I can't find the first item anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed prior answer, replacing with this per your additional request. Since you want to stack the B+ animals, you will need to create a combo chart, but in stages.  Maybe this isn't the easiest method, but it works.

First, create a scatterplot on Stack, Exposure. Add data labels, and then Format data labels. Check the box "values from cells" and select your animals. Then de-select Y-value check box. Your chart should currently look like this:

[image: Chart 1]

Next, delete your x-axis (remove those numbers). Then, right-click on chart and "select data". On the left side of the pop-up, click the ADD button and input these as your values:

```
Series Name: =F1
Series x-values: =F2:F6
Series y-values: =G2:G6
```

Click OK, OK.

Now your chart should look like this:

[image: Chart 2]

Next, right-click on chart and select Change Chart Type.
Select the Combo chart.

```
Exposure should be scattered plot (deselect secondary axis). 
Dummy_Rating should be clustered column.
```

Click OK.

Next, click on the chart, then on the Design Tab at top, and add chart element button, then add Primary Horizontal Axes. Delete your horizonal grid lines, and your chart is complete and should look like this:

[image: Chart Final]

Comment: thank you for the response! is it possible to stack the 2 different "B+" rated animals on the same point on the X-Axis so it looks like a more consistent X axis? The X axis should look like:  B, B+, A-... in that order with no doubles

Comment: I used the numeric dummy variables in order to try to accomplish this goal

Comment: Making updates to my answer now, give me a minutes.

Comment: just made a couple edits. If this is acceptable, please accept this one and the other on stackoverflow, thanks much.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! It may be good to copy and paste your answer over to Stack Overflow as well so future people can see the answer

Comment: Is there a way to reverse order from the X Axis on the final graph? So that it reads B, B+, A-... from left to right?

Comment: Yes, just rearrange all applicable data in columns B through G.